# Searching for strings with dashes with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I read a little online but couldn't find an answer. Suppose I have this line (and some other):

```
    olga gell-er tel-aviv 56 43
```

I want to use grep to look for a name in a file (let's say it only contains this line at the moment). The thing is I want to look for the exact string, including the "-". so if I search for olga gell , it won't find it in the file.

So far I've tried ($2 $3 are the string from the command line, $1 is the name of the file)

```
    grep -iwc ^"$2 $3" $1
```

but this options also finds me olga gell, which I don't want. so how do I fix this?

My command line looks something like this:

```
    change_team.bash players olga gell Real new2
```

change_team.bash is the name of the script. players is the file. "olga gell" is the name I'm searching for, and the rest is irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: In your file, will there always be a space after the name?

Comment: Suppose, there are two lines in the text file: "olga gell-er" and "olga gell ". Do you want to find the first one, but not the second?

Comment: yes, there always be a space between 2 arguments in the file

Comment: if I'mm looking for olga gell, I want to find the second but not the first, if I'm searching for olga gell-er I want to find the first but not the second

Comment: any reason why you have to put `-w` in option?

Comment: from what I read about grep if I don't have w he'll find the string even if it's part of another string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always a space after the name, just require the space as part of your pattern.

```
grep -iwc ^"$2 $3 " $1
```

Comment: just tried it, but if I search for "olga gell-er" he can't find it

Comment: The -w is likely throwing you off.  That will limit the results to matches containing whole words.  Remove the -w and you should be fine.

Comment: question. what's if it's a line with only one word so no spaces after the string. what can I do in that case?

Comment: Depending on how you're trying to accomplish this, you can anchor the results to the end of the line with $ in addition to the start of the line with ^ as you were doing in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The following solves your problem:

```
./scriptName.sh test olga gell[\w-]
```

Comment: This will find "geller", "gell-er", but not "gell ".